# importing card.io SDK into my existing android app

Tags: android, eclipse, card.io

How can I add **card.io Library** to my Android project?. I tried to researched but it didn't helped me. I extracted and Imported the SDK to my Eclipse(Luna), but then when I try to add the card.io library into my project, it doesn't show up on the project selection. I don't know what am I missing. Also,  I want to know what is the difference of the [card.io-Android-source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK)  to [card.io-Android-sdk](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source) , because I'm confuse of which is the right one to be imported into the Eclipse.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

using **card.io-Android-sdk**

1. unzip **card.io-5.0.1.aar** file
2. copy **classes.jar** And paste into **libs** folder in your eclipse
   project
3. and copy all folders from **jni folder**(contains .so file) And
   paste into **libs** folder in your eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your second question first with a third question: why not use Android Studio and Gradle to import card.io into your project?  If you follow the sample app example, the integration steps are very straightforward.

If you insist on Eclipse, [here's a suggestion](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) you could follow given the card.io `.aar` file.

Comment: Thank you, the [link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) you have given is still quite unclear to me and I got stucked up so I looked for another way... fortunately, I found a clearer and easier set-up [here](http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development)